# Mouse pad does not work on GNU/Linux for ASUS X552C laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, touchpad

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on an ASUS X552C laptop, along with w****** 8.

The mouse pad does not work. I have not been able to identify it with lspci. Several searches have not been successful. The default Kernel and some latest ones have been tested. I have observed the USB mouse also shows some anomalous behaviour (loosing buttons). As suggested by teknopaul, I also checked if the touchpad should appear as a USB device with lsusb, but it didn't.

I have heard ASUS is not being Linux friendly lately, so it may be there is no solution for this yet, but I decided to try here in case someone has stumbled on this too.

Comment: This seems to be a bug as suggested here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314198. There seems to be no solution yet, but the workaround suggested in this post to enable the minimal functions of the pad (i.e. adding the kernel option psmouse.proto=bare) does work indeed for X552C too.

Answer (score 0):

The only distros I can get to work well on this laptop are Trisquel and Centos 7. The  top 10 according to Distrowatch tempt one go back to Windows.
By the way, Centos finds the wireless net work but runs slowly, Trisquel does not find it.